# Why not have `Prop : Set` in Coq?

Tags: coq, predicativity, universe

My understanding of Coq is that `Prop : Type_1`, `Set : Type_1`, and then `Type_1 : Type_2`, `Type_2 : Type_3`, etc.

So, at the bottom level, the world splits into two universes: `Prop` (impredicative) and `Set` (predicative, like all the other `Type_i` universes). My question is: why not just have `Prop : Type_0 : Type_1 : Type_2 : ...`, with `Prop` being impredicative as it is today, and all the other levels would be predicative, also as is the case today? Wouldn't that be simpler? Would cumulatively still work?

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe `Set` is not actually predicative

Comment: @Couchy why do you say that?

Comment: It seems this is no longer the case, as Pierre-Marie Pédrot answered

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As it often happens with Coq, the answer is *historical reasons*.

In the original version dating back from 1984, Coq was based on the Calculus of Constructions, a barebone dependent type theory. In particular, it did not feature inductive types. Instead, following the PTS tradition, it had impredicative universes.

The introduction of inductive types did not change this state of affair, and for a long time Coq had *two* impredicative universes, `Prop` and `Set`. The difference between both lied in the fact that the former was erased by extraction, but not the latter. This phase separation had been around for a long time already.

When dealing with several impredicative universes, one has to be extremely careful because proofs of `False` lurk around the corner. In particular, `Prop : Set` when both are impredicative is enough be a variant of Girard's system U⁻  and thus inconsistent. The Coq developers of yore were well aware of this issue and relied on an alternative hierarchy, so that `Prop : Type` and `Set : Type`.

Now, at some point it was decided to make `Set` predicative by default, for other somewhat related reasons. Indeed, impredicative proof-relevant universes are very much inconsistent with many slightly classical principles like excluded middle in `Type` or some forms of choice. In particular and ironically, with an impredicative `Set`, Coq has no set-theoretical model (as in [*Polymorphism is not set-theoretic*](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00076261/document)). Nowadays, `Set` is thus predicative except if the user opts in impredicativity with a specific flag.

Impredicative set is essentially not used as of today, and really not tested so it has fallen to bitrot. It is extremely likely that it is not usable anymore, and there is an [evergreen discussion about its removal](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/9458). Yet, since the flag still exists Coq needs to at least pretend to avoid inconsistencies when the user sets it, and therefore one cannot have `Prop : Set`.

If the flag ever gets removed, maybe we can consider adding this rule, but then there might be weird backwards incompatibilities. Therefore, it is not even clear we will ever perform this change even in a situation where it is perfectly sound.